# Calculate $\iiint_{\| Ax \|_2 \leq 1} d\vec{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices

> Suppose $A$ is a non-singular $3\times3$ matrix. Calculate 
>   $$\iiint_{\| A \vec{x} \|_2 \leq 1} d\vec{x}.$$ 
>   where $\| \vec{y} \|_2$ is the Euclidean norm.

This question was asked when I attended my PhD application's interview. I managed to work out the special case $A = 1,$ and the answer I obtained is $\frac{4 \pi}{3}$. However, I have no idea how to work with general $A$.

In the end, I could not obtain the answer for it. The interviewer told me that it can be solved by change of variables and Jacobian matrix. In the end, I was not admitted into the university.

Can anyone guide me on how to solve the integral? Also, where can I obtain more questions of this kind or in the same field? Currently I am preparing and polishing my PhD application documents so that I can get admitted into the same university this time.

Comment: Hint: This is the volume of something.

Comment: I think it is the volume of an ellipse?

Comment: Change variable to $\vec{y} = A\vec{x}$ and notice $$\prod_i dx_i = \left|\verb/det/\left(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y_j}\right)\right| \prod_j dy_j 
= \left|\verb/det/A^{-1}\right|\prod_j dy_j
= \left|\verb/det/A\right|^{-1} \prod_j dy_j
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint $\|A x\|_2\leq 1$ can be written as $x^T (A^t A) x\leq 1$, and by the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) $A^t A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ having on its diagonal positive numbers $r_1^2,\ldots,r_n^2$. Since the conjugation $A^t A\sim D$ is provided by an isometry, we simply have

$$ \int_{\|A x\|_2\leq 1}1\,d\mu = \int_{r_1^2 x_1^2+\ldots+r_n^2 x_n^2 \leq 1}1\,d\mu = \frac{1}{\left|r_1\cdots r_n\right|}\int_{u_1^2+\ldots+u_n^2\leq 1}1\,d\mu $$
and the original integral equals the product between $\frac{1}{\left|\det A\right|}$ and the volume of the $n$-dimensional [unit ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere):
$$ \int_{\|A x\|_2\leq 1}1\,d\mu = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(1+n/2)\left|\det A\right|}}. $$
It is, indeed, the volume of an ellipsoid.

Comment: Thanks for the general formula. When $n=3$, we have $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(3/2) |det A|}$?

Comment: @Idonknow: for $n=3$ we have $$\frac{4\pi}{3\left|\det A\right|}$$ after simplifying $\pi^{3/2}$ and $\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)=\frac{3}{4}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{\pi}$.